# How to merge these two similar js function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I merge these two functions?

```
$("#f-box").droppable({
    accept: "#f-cwrapper > div",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        deletecard(ui.draggable);
    }
});

$("#l-box").droppable({
    accept: "#l-cwrapper > div",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        deletecard(ui.draggable);
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by merge? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I mean how can I combine these two similar functions into one function.

Comment: This *is* one function: `droppable`. You are invoking the same with similar parameters in two different statements. First, why not just call the function twice? Can you use classes instead of ids? If you used classes instead of ids, you could call the function once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are both statements. There is only one function involved: `droppable`. These two statements call the `droppable` function twice, each time with different parameters.

If what you're asking is, "Is there a way to write the two statments as a single statement? Sure. For example,

```
$( "#f-box, #l-box" ).droppable({
  accept: function () { return "#" + this.id.charAt(0) + "-cwrapper > div"},
  drop: function (event, ui) {
        deletecard(ui.draggable);
    }
});
```

However, that single statement will be worse than two statements by about any metric of judging code. There is no duplication, but I think this code is harder to read and more fragile. The function we have introduced to calculate the `accept` selector is the most complex part of the code now.

I assume your intention is to remove duplication. That is the "code smell" this code has. There are a few things you could do, but whether any of these improves the code will be a judgement call.

The first comment is that you use an anonymous function more than once. You could name the function and remove some duplication that way:

```
var drop = function (event, ui) {
        deletecard(ui.draggable);
};

$("#f-box").droppable({
    accept: "#f-cwrapper > div",
    drop: drop
});

$("#l-box").droppable({
    accept: "#l-cwrapper > div",
    drop: drop
});
```

One of the common ways to get rid of duplicate code is a refactoring named "extract method." You could create a extract a function whose parameters are the differences between the statements, then call the function twice:

```
function createDroppable(droppableSelector, acceptSelector) {
    $(droppableSelector).droppable({
    accept: acceptSelector,
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        deletecard(ui.draggable);
    }
});    
createDroppable("#l-box","#l-cwrapper > div");
createDroppable("#f-box","#f-cwrapper > div");
```

Comment: I'm curious, why the chartAt?

Comment: the l and f in the id